# How to find bridge current in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

I have this circuit shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1BWvj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically this circuit has two inputs and two outputs. The voltage and current at the inputs are defined as: $$V_{1}^{in},I_{1}^{in},V_{3}^{in},I_{3}^{in}$$

and at the output:

$$V_{2}^{out},I_{2}^{out},V_{4}^{out},I_{4}^{out}$$

I know, I can represent these four elements (if you combine RLC together) by using transfer matrix as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1}^{out}\\
I_{1}^{out}
\end{bmatrix} = T_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1}^{in}\\
I_{1}^{in}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_{2}^{out}\\
I_{2}^{out}
\end{bmatrix} = T_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
V_{2}^{in}\\
I_{2}^{in}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_{3}^{out}\\
I_{3}^{out}
\end{bmatrix} = T_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
V_{3}^{in}\\
I_{3}^{in}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_{4}^{out}\\
I_{4}^{out}
\end{bmatrix} = T_{4}\begin{bmatrix}
V_{4}^{in}\\
I_{4}^{in}
\end{bmatrix}$$

On the other hand we know that: $$I_{1}^{out} - I_{2}^{in} = I_{b}$$ and $$I_{3}^{out} - I_{4}^{in} = -I_{b}$$ where $$I_{b}$$ is defined as:

$$I_{b} = \frac{V_{1}^{out}-V_{3}^{out}}{R} = \frac{V_{2}^{in}-V_{4}^{in}}{R}$$

Also we know:

$$V_{1}^{out} = V_{2}^{in}$$

$$V_{3}^{out} = V_{4}^{in}$$

As a result finally we have this matrix equation for this circuit:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_{2}^{out}\\
I_{2}^{out}\\
V_{4}^{out}\\
I_{4}^{out}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
T_{2}T_{1} & 0 \\
0 & T_{4}T_{3}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
V_{1}^{in}\\
I_{1}^{in}\\
V_{3}^{in}\\
I_{3}^{in}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
-T_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
I_{b}
\end{bmatrix}\\
T_{4}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
I_{b}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The above matrix equation gives me 4 equations but, I have 5 unknowns. My known parameters are:

$$I_{1}^{in},I_{3}^{in},V_{2}^{out},V_{4}^{out}$$

and my unknown parameters are:

$$V_{1}^{in},V_{3}^{in},I_{2}^{out},I_{4}^{out},I_{b}$$

Is there any way to find $I_{b}$ here without further assumption?

Comment: What do the capacitors connect to?

Comment: @Andyaka All the capacitors are connected to the ground.

Comment: Is input on right? Or left?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The 1 and 3 on the left are the inputs and 2 and 4 are the outputs on the right.

Comment: What is the input waveform f and V. Zc=1/(2Pi *fC] then Ic(f)=V(f)/Zc. Then for 3kV spikes 4us rise time f=0.35/Tr

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Actually on the left side the input waveforms are $I_{1}^{in}$ and $I_{3}^{in}$ which are periodic and could be represented at each frequency by using the FFT. At the right side, I fix the value of $V_{2}^{out}$ and $V_{4}^{out}$.

Comment: So what is V(f)?????

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 which V(f)? In the inputs (left side) or in the outputs (right side)?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 if you are asking about what capacitors are connected to, as I said all the capacitors are connected to the ground. But other than that I'm not sure what V(f) you are asking for.

Comment: The ground shunt caps draw current up to 2.5mA for CE approval but generally 0.5mA with no load . Your question is poorly defined for electrical environment

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm not sure about this cause honestly I'm not an electrical engineer but this question is just about a circuit that comes from a very different field for simulating blood flow in human arteries and just represented as circuit in analogy to electrical circuits for better understanding. So, it's not like these kind of circuits might be produced or should maintain a minimum standard for current or whatever. It's more about theory of circuits and just be able to formulaize this circuit and possibly find  a formula for $I_{b}$.

Comment: Then your question must define the requirements for uA leakage to gnd and signal current to choose C given CM line noise and ECG RLD rejection. The simulation is easy to do on Falstad’s web sim..well easy for me

Comment: It is easy to design a matched filter to signal BW and leakage and differential conduction current from source impedance.  BUT these must be defined. You are analyzing this backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include one of these equations (that you already gave):

$$I_b = \frac{V_1^{out}-V_3^{out}}{R}$$

or

$$I_b = \frac{V_2^{out}-V_4^{out}}{R}$$

This should give you 5 equations and 5 unknowns.

[edit] I did not redo your calculations. Don't hold it against me if there was an error in there somewhere.